# not able to perform multitasking in linq to sql data context

Tags: c#, linq, web-services, linq-to-sql

I have Windows Service which will handle JOBs posted via web sites, user can request long running job to WS. WS will pick that job and do necessary calculation with data and update the data into database. The number of record update more than 15 lacks.

**So the issue is if the JOB is running via WS and same time if you try to access the website or if you try to perform any operation on the page it will show lodging page till the WS will finish the task.**

The Web Application & WS is using common database via LINQ to SQL DBML. The Data Access layer is separate class library and referred by WS and Web Application. The database is in SQL Server 2008 R2

I am not able to find the root cause of the above.

Please help on this

Comment: How is the windows service triggered is it called from the site or is it just monitoring the website.  If you use SqlAnalyser is it showing that any processes are blocking others when the problem occurs.

Comment: WS will check in DB for in job request at regular interval and if any one in queue then WS will execute the job

Comment: This will be dependent on your code. But you didn't _show_ us your code,so we can't help you.

Comment: Code is too long the process is like this Get All the records from Database for calculation do the calculation and save all the records.

Comment: You could be holding a lock on the database for all the records, Are you holding the connection open during the calculation?

Answer (score 0):

By mistake I have made DataContext object as static.
DataContext object never be static.